# Two is not Two - Select case condition never matches

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

I'd like to know if a certain behaviour of my function in VBA is a bug or if there is something wrong with my code. I also would appreciate suggestions if it is a bug, how I could solve the problem.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function someFunction(dblWeight As Double) As Integer
  Dim x As Integer

  Select Case dblWeight
    Case Is <= 0.25: x = 1
    Case Is <= 0.5: x = 2
    Case Is <= 0.75: x = 3
    Case Is <= 1: x = 4
    Case Is <= 1.25: x = 5
    Case Is <= 1.5: x = 6
    Case Is <= 1.75: x = 7
    Case Is <= 2: x = 8
    Case Is <= 3: x = 9
    Case Is <= 4: x = 10
    Case Is <= 5: x = 11
    Case Is <= 10: x = 12
    Case Else: x = 13
  End Select

  someFunction = x
End Function
```

If I call this function directly from VBA code, all results are as expected. If I call this function from a cell in Excel, it gets odd:

```
         A       B       C
1      1.9       8       '=someFunction(A1)
2      2.0       9       '=someFunction(A2)
3      2.1       9       '=someFunction(A3)
```

In column A the values to check against the function are entered as numbers - not as text.
In column B you see the result returned.
In column C I show you the function call which leads to the result shown in column B.

The question is: why is 2.0 not less or equal 2?

What I already tried:

- given argument to the function "ByRef" and not "ByVal"
- forcing the values which are obviously not double to be double by adding a # (like "Case Is <= 2# : x = 8")
- replace the switch construct by an If construct
- giving solid ranges (like "Case 1.751 To 2 : x = 8")
- thought it might be a messed up installation of Excel or a defective Excel workbook but it also happens on other machines with completely new workbooks

All these didn't help. And what makes it even more mysterious is the fact, that it only happens with the value 2. If I change the value in the excel sheet from 2.0 to 1.0 I get a 4 as result and not a 5 - so this behaviour is not even consistent.

I'm completely perplexed and don't find a way around this, so any help with this would be great.

Greetings

Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: why is 2.0 not less or equal 2?

When the *2* is not *2.000000000000000* but off by an infinitesimally small amount. Excel works on a 15 digit floating point precision. Very small differences in how the 15th digit is rounded off lead to floating point error.

I would suggest rounding off *dblWeight* like this.

```
  Select Case Round(dblWeight, 4)
```

That 4 digit precision should be more than adequate for your scope of 2 decimal numbers.

See [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113).

Comment: Works, but doesn't explain the behaviour. I enter the number manally - even if I enter it as 2 and not 2.0 it messes up. And as stated in the question, this doesn't happen with the value 1 - so I'd still like to know why. I also debugged the function and the value given from the excel sheet is printed as 2.0 and not as 2.0.....?

Comment: I can only reproduce the behavior if I use a complicated function that involves repeating decimals or time values; both of which are prime sources of floating point errors. If I type in a *2* to the worksheet, I do not get that error with your function as pasted into a VBA module. The link I supplied explains the reason for the behavior better than I can.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just removed your solution from the code to experiment further and now my Excel kids me even more. Now it works correctly even without the rounding. So the circumstances seem to be identical but to produce different results. I give up on this and will go on with your suggestion to round the value as I think it will at least help to avoid this problem in the future.